# Postgres SSL on Amazon RDS without supplying pub key?

Tags: java, postgresql, ssl, amazon-web-services, rds

Given this connection command

```
psql --host=test-psql-db.xxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --username=someuser --password  "dbname=somedb"
```

I see this result

```
psql (9.4.1, server 9.3.5)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

somedb=>
```

So I have an SSL connection, but I did not supply Amazon's public key for my RDS instance, below is the connection command I *thought* I needed to use to achieve SSL encryption

```
 psql --host=test-psql-db.xxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --username=someuser --password  "sslmode=verify-full sslrootcert=rds-ssl-ca-cert.pem  dbname=somedb"
```

Which yields the same result

```
psql (9.4.1, server 9.3.5)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

stamp4s_test=>
```

So is my connection secure without the public key? I'm not sure I'm understanding the entire picture here.

Comment: Does `~/.postgresql/root.crt` already contain the root certificate presented by the server ?

Comment: So I do have  /etc/postgresql-common/root.crt on my local machine (the client connecting to the RDS instance) so are we thinking this is supplied by default?

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/libpq-ssl.html) notes that `root.crt` is passed by default. Perhaps the default location has been tweaked in AWS ? An easy experiment would be to rename this file or to find all `root.crt` files on the disk and check which one is picked up.

Comment: So a closer look at the [AWS Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL) seems to indicate that supplying a pub key includes the DB endpoint as the Common Name, which guards against spoofing attacks, which is solving a different problem than I intended. So my data should be encrypted without supplying the pub key, just I won't be validating endpoints?

Comment: Endpoint validation is taken care of under the `verify-full` mode through the `CN` attribute. You're never supplying a public key to RDS. You're setting the location of the root CA cert file that the client should use to determine if the server's certificate is valid. The host name of the server and the value in the CN attribute should match in `verify-full` mode. What does this command show when you run it - `export | grep PGSSLROOTCERT`

Comment: Still can't get it. All connections with psql on my rds instance will be ssl encrypted?  `export | grep PGSSLROOTCERT` shows me nothing. I don't have `~/.postgresql/root.crt` or `/etc/postgresql-common/root.crt`

Answer (score 3):

Postgre server cert is always trusted by default.
Connection will be crypted, but the server identity isn't verified w/o pub key.

Postgre docs:
31.17.1. Client Verification of Server Certificates
By default, PostgreSQL will not perform any verification of the server certificate.